# deleting california-calendar completely

Tags: command-line, calendar

I am a complete newbie in Linux and I was wondering (if) what is the safest way to delete the calendar "california", including all the files from my device. ( california is not needed anymore!)

I have found this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove california
```

but i don't know if it is safe.

Comment: Easiest way: look for it on ubuntu software and remove.

Answer (score 2):

Apps in ubuntu is normally deleted through the apt-get purge command.

i would do this

```
sudo apt-get purge california
```

then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

the last two clears your computer from stuffs that is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

That will safely remove the package and all associated configuration files, as well as any packages which were installed because that package was installed.

No other files will be touched.

The only time when running this would be "risky" is if you have manually installed other non-packaged software which depends on either the package or another package which was automatically installed at the same time.  If you're not sure about this, then the answer is almost certainly "yes, go ahead and run the purge command".

If you want to be even safer, then just run `apt-get remove` instead.  If that's working fine, you can go-ahead and run `apt-get purge` at a later time.